# r — what’s a more stream-oriented (%>%) idiom for map(map(Auto, range), function(col) {paste0(col[[1]], “,” col[[2]])})

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

The following code iterates all columns of the given dataframe (“Auto” from built-in R examples),

gets the range of the entire column,

then converts the range from range-obj to str-format for viewing

```
library(purrr)
map(map(Auto, range), function(col) {paste0(col[[1]], "," col[[2]])})
```

I’d like to make this even more stream-oriented (`dplyr`). I’ve given it a go with wrapping in `tibble()` and `rowwise()`, but am unable to do it.

Comment: Your code doesn't work for a couple of trivial reasons. You have smart quotes around the comma in `","`. I changed them to straight quotes. You need a comma after `","` in your `paste0` call. And you don't show us what values are stored in the object `Auto`.

Comment: Another option for fun: `map(mtcars, ~paste(range(.x), collapse = ', ')) `. Also works with the other `map_` calls, e.g. `map_df` or `map_chr`.

Comment: @Josh ah ok, thanks. I’ll try to check it next time. As you could tell, I transpasted it from my computer1 to my browsing-computer2 using eyeball :D

Comment: @nniloc Very cool! Look forward to keeping that one in mind too. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer using `map` in this case (one `map` call is enough), but you can also use `across` from {dplyr} (see examples below). In the case of the latter the output will be a `data.frame` and it will contain one row with many list columns, which in turn hold both values of `range`. You could also drop the list and just have a `data.frame` with two rows, containing `min` and `max`.

Btw. `rowwise` won't help here, because we need to operate on the whole column to get its `range`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mtcars %>% 
map( ~ paste(range(.x)[1],
             range(.x)[2],
             sep = ", "))
#> $mpg
#> [1] "10.4, 33.9"
#> 
#> $cyl
#> [1] "4, 8"
#> 
#> $disp
#> [1] "71.1, 472"
#> 
#> $hp
#> [1] "52, 335"
#> 
#> $drat
#> [1] "2.76, 4.93"
#> 
#> $wt
#> [1] "1.513, 5.424"
#> 
#> $qsec
#> [1] "14.5, 22.9"
#> 
#> $vs
#> [1] "0, 1"
#> 
#> $am
#> [1] "0, 1"
#> 
#> $gear
#> [1] "3, 5"
#> 
#> $carb
#> [1] "1, 8"

mtcars %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(),
                   ~ paste(range(.x)[1],
                           range(.x)[2],
                           sep = ", ") %>% 
                     list))
#>          mpg  cyl      disp      hp       drat           wt       qsec   vs
#> 1 10.4, 33.9 4, 8 71.1, 472 52, 335 2.76, 4.93 1.513, 5.424 14.5, 22.9 0, 1
#>     am gear carb
#> 1 0, 1 3, 5 1, 8

mtcars %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), range))
#>    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1 10.4   4  71.1  52 2.76 1.513 14.5  0  0    3    1
#> 2 33.9   8 472.0 335 4.93 5.424 22.9  1  1    5    8
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>